# nested element - make background take up full height of parent

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list nested inside a footer element. I'd like to make some of the lines have a background that takes up the full height of the parent element but when I try to do this there is a margin or padding somewhere and I cannot figure out where. I have tried combination of altering display, margin and padding settings with no joy.

```
<footer> 
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/facebooklogo.png" alt="facebook icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="design.htm" >design</a></li>
<li><a href="salvage.htm" >salvage</a></li>
<li><a href="suigeneris.htm" >sui generis</a></li>
<li><a href="flooring.htm" >flooring</a></li>
<li><a href="paneling.htm" >paneling</a></li>
<li><a href="beams.htm" >beams</a></li>
<li><a href="reclaimedwood.htm" >reclaimed wood</a></li>
</ul>

</footer>

footer {
width: 100%;
background: #80A353;
}

footer .navigation li a {
display: block;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
background: white;
}

footer .navigation {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 850px;
}
```

Any insight appreciated

Comment: You use "footer" as if it's tag, but I suppose it's class name or id. If so firstly you need to fix it.

Comment: .navigation is a class of UL. Since I only wish to affect those lists within the footer element I have written "footer .navigation" as a selector. Is there another way I should select this UL and it's children? I am a newbie. Using HTML5

Comment: you need to post of your code to get incite. Or show us the problem.

Comment: Please describe clearly what's the problem. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ service to try your code and see what's wrong and if you can't solve it at least you could share the link.

Comment: @Kate: You must not have heard of HTML5. And Doug, since you're using HTML5, you may as well put that `<ul>` in a `<nav>` and remove the `.navigation` class.

Comment: If you can't see where the margin or padding is coming from, you need to think of line-height(<a> tag style). Specifying line-height would help as <a> tag has no height defined even though it is a block element. So, it just takes the line-height when it contains plain text.
Can't help more as you haven't provided much info.

Comment: @ BoltClock Yes, you are right. I didn't use HTML5 before, only HTML4. But Doug didn't note that it was exactly html5 - I mean he added this information later.

Comment: @BoltClock. I do have a main navigation at the top of the page inside the nav element. It was my understanding that this "sub" or "crumb" navigation, since not the main navigation, should not go inside the nav element, as it is in the footer?

Comment: figured it out - I have two unordered lists on the page and the previous one had a solid border which threw me off. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact dimentions, making something take up full height can be done with the following:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: ###px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If you have another element inside parent, you can use this technique to make one of the children full height.

If you want multiple elements of equal height, and IE<=7 support is not required, you can do the following:

```
.parent { display: table; }

.child { display: table-cell; }
```